# Order of React Context Providers

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

If I have multiple context providers, does the order matter? It does seem like it does, but I can't find any official documentation on it.

For instance:

```
<SessionProvider>
  <AuthProvider>
    <App />
  </AuthProvider>
</SessionProvider>
```

The above seems to execute the `useEffect` code within the `AuthProvider` before it executes it within `SessionProvider` (both of which are utilizing React context).

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It shouldn't matter unless they're interacting with each other. They execute from the inside out because `AuthProvider` receives `<App />` as the `children` prop, and then `SessionProvider` receives `<AuthProvider><App /></AuthProvider>` as the `children` prop.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Gotcha, that makes sense, thank you! For some reason I thought things would be executed from top-to-bottom, but maybe that's just my misunderstanding of how React renders components.

Comment: It generally does, it's only bottom-up when the JSX is nested. But if all of your components were shallow, then it would be top-down. In any case, you should not rely on order of execution anyway because doing so would imply you keep state outside of React.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks for clarifying. The main reason I'm depending on the order of execution is because within AuthProvider I'm making a request to backend to authenticate a user and get an access_token back. Then, within `SessionProvider`, I'm making another request that gets session data that depends on whether a user is authenticated or not from the `AuthProvider`. There might be a better way to do this, but it all seems to be working for now.

Answer (score 1):

Actually if you're not using `session` context inside of `auth` context or there isn't any nested context used, it doesn't matter.

But if you're using some data originated from `SessionProvider` inside of `AuthProvider`, of course The `Session` context data must be available in `AuthProvider`, hence the `Session` must be used as the top parent element.